# How to get URL from Block Text in Cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with Text in A1:

> Welcome to my Website!
>
> Visit some Amazon Products: https://amzn.to/3o7UGKS
>
> King regards!

So what I'm looking for is how to get the link Amazon Link from the text in cell A1 in B1?
B1 should be:

> https://amzn.to/3o7UGKS

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"@"),"(http[^~]+)@")`

This formula assumes that your line breaks are caused by ASCII character 10.